# getting up to date contents of an iFrame

Tags: iframe

Is it possible to get up to date contents from an iframe? Lemme explain the problem I am encountering:

```
function modify_iframe(url){
  my_iframe.src  = url;
  iframe_content = my_iframe.contentDocument;
  //....code to modify the content goes here,,,,
}
```

The first time I call `modify_iframe(url_a)` it sets the source as I would expect but the iframe_content is a blank document.

The second time I run `modify_iframe(url_b)` it sets the source as I would expect but the `iframe_content` is actually that of `url_a`.

So it seems that contentDocument is not returning the contents of the new source, but rather the source before it was changed.  Anyone know why that is and if there is a way around it?

Additional background info: We have been adding an event listener to fire off on the iframe load event which occurs when the src is changed. This was giving us the contents when calling contentDocument; however, users were being prompted that our site had unauthenticated content even though we use https for everything including the src. After removing the event listener we no longer receive the unauthenticated content warning, but the contentDocument of our iframe is always one step behind as described above.

Answer (score 0):

Um, first try using a setTimeout to wait for the page content to load. But that's not a nice solution. What browser are you testing on? If it were me I would try to get to the bottom of the "unauthenticated content" error prompt.